# Why Quartz scheduler's unscheduleJob is deleting both trigger and job detail?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Im trying to execute the following quartz scheduler code in the a cluster environment.

```
scheduler.unscheduleJob("genericJobTrigger", "DEFAULT");
```

where as

```
Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler) context.getBean("scheduler");
JobDetail genericJob = (JobDetail) context.getBean("genericJob");
CronTrigger genericJobTrigger = (CronTrigger) context.getBean("genericJobTrigger");
```

Above piece of code is deleting entries from trigger and job detail. It supposed to remove only trigger right?

Why Quartz scheduler's unscheduleJob is deleting both trigger and job detail?

Comment: Because it's really not a good idea to leave triggers hanging around with no jobs to fire. It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

durability is set true to Jobs to avoid deleting the JOBS when Triggers are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are creating an object of `JobDetail` then set `storeDurably()`, refer the below example:

```
return JobBuilder.newJob(ScheduledJob.class)
                .setJobData(jobDataMap)
                .withDescription("job executes at specified frequency")
                .withIdentity(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "email-jobs")
                .storeDurably() //This will not allow to delete automatially
                .build();
```

Also you can verify it by checking the value of `IS_DURABLE` column in `jobDetails` table.